# Add data query with Hive-JSON-SerDe

Tags: json, hive, hiveql

I'm working with hive and i need to add data in json-format. I use https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde library. It loads data in hive from file.

```
~$ cat test.json

{"text":"foo","number":123}
{"text":"bar","number":345}

$ hadoop fs -put -f test.json /user/data/test.json

$ hive

hive> CREATE DATABASE test;

hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test ( text string )
      ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
      LOCATION '/user/data';

hive> SELECT * FROM test;
OK

foo 123
bar 345
```

But i need load data from query, like:

```
insert into table test values {"text": "abc", number: 666}
```

Who knows how do this?

Answer (score 1):

The question seems old, however, in case someone looking for an answer:

I tried another approach as following:

1. `Create table test (text string);`
2. `LOAD data inpath 'path/test.json' INTO TABLE test;`
3. `insert into table test values ("{'text':'abc','number':666}");`

The only different is when you need to load values it will be something like:

```
select get_json_object(str,'$.text') as text1, get_json_object(str,'$.number') as number1 from test;
```

Answer (score 0):

A SerDe is really intended for use with external tables which read the data from files containing the data. So it will not help you directly insert json data and the insert query you give as an example will not work as such. I suggest that you should either write the data to a file on your hdfs and create an external table on the folder containing the file, or parse incoming data such that you can insert it as columns.